# Download File Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, file, download

How can I prompt a download for a user when they click a link.

For example, instead of:

```
<a href="uploads/file.doc">Download Here</a>
```

I could use:

```
<a href="#">Download Here</a>

 $('a').click... //Some jquery to download the file
```

This way, Google does not index my HREF's and private files.

Can this be done with jQuery, if so, how?  Or should this be done with PHP or something instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 190, accepted):

I might suggest this, as a more gracefully degrading solution, using [`preventDefault`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'uploads/file.doc';
});

<a href="no-script.html">Download now!</a>
```

Even if there's no Javascript, at least this way the user will get some feedback.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  I usually use "preventDefault", just left it out above because I was being lazy.  ;-)

Comment: Works great, but get some MIME type errors. Curious if there are any ways to get past them?

Comment: Did you solve MIME type warning? I get "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type..." Many thanks.

Comment: Im confused. How is this still  marked as an answer? Whatever href you put will follow the link. This doesn't work in anyway.

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want search engines to index certain files, you can use [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) to tell web spiders not to access certain parts of your website.

If you rely only on javascript, then some users who browse without it won't be able to click your links.

Comment: Good to know about the 'robots.txt'.  Thank you.

Comment: @Rob, If you need the URLs to be "private", `robots.txt` wouldn't help because it would still be stored in the browser history and intermediary servers.

Comment: 6 years later: browsing without javascript? - well, you could also go for a walk instead.

Comment: nearly 10 years later: same! or ?

Answer (score 17):

Here's a nice article that shows many ways of hiding files from search engines:

> http://antezeta.com/news/avoid-search-engine-indexing

JavaScript isn't a good way not to index a page; it won't prevent users from linking directly to your files (and thus revealing it to crawlers), and as Rob mentioned, wouldn't work for all users.
An easy fix is to add the `rel="nofollow"` attribute, though again, it's not complete without robots.txt.

```
<a href="uploads/file.doc" rel="nofollow">Download Here</a>
```

Comment: [Here is another aricle of Google Help for Webmasers](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=de&answer=96569) which helps me a lot to understand the "nofollow" or "me" rel.

Answer (score 13):

```
 var link=document.createElement('a');
 document.body.appendChild(link);
 link.href=url;
 link.click();
```

Comment: no error, just download was not starting. i think there maybe some point im missing while creating element.

Comment: verify in your html if an element <a> was created or no and verify your file link .

Comment: a tag was there, in body. and by manual clicking it's downloading image. however it's not needed now, I used this vanillaJS solution.

Comment: there are no reason for not working are the link correct . test the link direct in browse

Comment: `$('blah').each(function(){
$('body').append('<a href="'+xxx+'" download="'+dynamicname+'" />'); })
$('a').trigger('click');` i used that.

Comment: add this document.body.appendChild(link);

Comment: This one worked for me, but i had to add 
`link.download = ${file name to download}` because was throwing me an error otherwise

Answer (score 13):

- Using jQuery function

  ```
      var valFileDownloadPath = 'http//:'+'your url';

     window.open(valFileDownloadPath , '_blank');
  ```

Comment: Hi, this one will open new tab, how if don't want open new tab, just direct download when clicked? already remove `_blank` but no action.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you would have to change the window.location.href to the url of the file you would want to download.

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.com/path/to/file';
```

Comment: what if the file extension is .html, instead of download it will redirect to that html file

Answer (score 7):

By stating `window.location.href = 'uploads/file.doc';` you show where you store your files. You might of course use .htacess to force the required behaviour for stored files, but this might not always be handful....

It is better to create a server side php-file and place this content in it:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_REQUEST['f']);
readfile('../some_folder/some_subfolder/'.$_REQUEST['f']); 
exit;
```

This code will return ANY file as a download without showing where you actually store it.

You open this php-file via `window.location.href = 'scripts/this_php_file.php?f=downloaded_file';`

Comment: This solution helped me fix the download issues on my site, thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer solved my problem! Too many reference that I tried but nothing help.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the mousedown event, which is called BEFORE the click event.
That way, the browser handles the click event naturally, which avoids any code weirdness:

```
(function ($) {


    // with this solution, the browser handles the download link naturally (tested in chrome and firefox)
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var url = '/private/downloads/myfile123.pdf';
        $("a").on('mousedown', function () {
            $(this).attr("href", url);
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with html5 very easily:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "/WWW/test.pdf";
link.download = "file_" + new Date() + ".pdf";
link.click();
link.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy This

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.setAttribute('download', '');
link.href = URL_HERE;
link.click();
link.remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

If somebody comes across this question looking for a way to force downloading an image for example. You could use a [download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_download.asp) on your <a> tag for that.

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```