# creating folders using jquery

Tags: jquery, download

I'm downloading files using the below code.
Can I create folders dynamically and download files to each folder for each category of requiredKeyWords

```
$.each(requiredCities,function(keya,valb){
        $.each(requiredKeyWords,function(keyc,vald){
            var timerId = setInterval(function(){
            download(...);
            clearInterval(timerId);
            }, 4000*(i++));    
        });
    });
});

function download(url){
    ...
}
```

thank you

Comment: You want to create folders in the client OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. JavaScript is sandboxed within the browser, giving you no access to the user's machine.

Really, it's for the best: Imagine every Joe and Jill can automagically create, move, read and alter things on your computer. That'd be a gianormous security hazard.

Comment: It isn't all true. All the times browsers can do downloads, since the user accepts it. From the asked question, we can ensure that the OP will never find a way to create specific folders on the user machine, but will surely can to start a download on the browser.

Comment: @ErickPetru - Of course he can download, but he asked to create folders and put the downloaded files into them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a request using jQuery (like `ajax()` or `post()` methods) and get a `HttpResponse` with the file content and the desired headers. Obviously you'll need a server-side technology (ASP.NET, Java, PHP etc.) to receive the `HttpRequest` and return the `HttpResponse`.

Then, *your browser will intercept this response as a download*.

Also, you can simple redirect the URL to the file, whithout manual post, like pointed on this thred: [Download File Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery). In this case, the browser will do the request for you, read the response and interpret as a download.

But **you cannot specifies where the user will choose to save** the file (nor the name). Also, the user always can cancel any download. And finally, the browser's security can be configurated to deny downloads.

Finally is important to remeber that the browser will show a download window per time. Then, you cannot start 10 downloads at the same time. Do you use Gmail? As you can see there, when a user wants to download all attachments at the same time, Gmail creates a ZIP with all files inside and sends the download of that ZIP. This is the better automatized way to do it, but also don't is what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, no. When running in a web browser, javascript has no access to the file system. That would be a massive security hole. The only way you can do that is using an ActiveX control, or a Java applet. Both options are evil.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in IE using ActiveX but not in other browsers.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/JavaScript__File_Handling.aspx

> "There are a few things to note before
>   implementing FileSystemObject. Since
>   its an ActiveX object it will not be
>   created if the security level on the
>   client machine is high. So the website
>   have to be added to the trusted site
>   list so that the ActiveX object can be
>   created.
>
> The user must have write access in the
>   path specified while creating a file.
>   In cases where there is uncertainty
>   its better to write the file onto
>   Temporary Folder of the system. The
>   path for the Temp folder can be found
>   using"