# Asynchronous PHP?

Tags: php, linux, system

I have a PHP script that does a lot of checks and then downloads a file to the server and outputs the original. 
 To download the file I use

```
system("/usr/local/bin/wget -O ...");
```

So php waits for the download to finish and then it outputs the file.
 
My question is if its possible to send a "ping" somewhere (other php file?) for the download to start and then without waiting for the result just continue with the execution.

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery ?

Comment: No, sorry. jQuery has nothing to do here

Answer (score 2):

Use `curl_multi_*` functions to handle multiple-downloads in parallel. PHP lacks any kind of threading support and process forking is merely a hack.

Comment: I dont have multiple downloads, the file is only one. I just want to continue executing while the file is downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pcntl_fork()` to fork your current process into a child process. Do the file download in the child process while your parent process can continue executing its task.

```
$pid = pcntl_fork(); 

if ( $pid == -1 ) 
{        
    // Fork failed            
    exit(1); 
} 
else if ( $pid ) 
{ 
    // The parent process
   //continue what you want to do here
} 
else 
{ 
    // the child process 
    // do the system call here
}
```

After doing some work, if you now need to parent process to wait until the child process finishes, you can `pcntl_waitpid($pid)`.

Read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcntl.php) for more documentation on pcntl methods.

Comment: pcntrl functions are not recommended for use in web environments and only work on *nix systems - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php

Comment: Since he tagged the question linux, I think we can safely assume he's running it in a linux box. As for your other point, you are correct. Pcnlt functions only run from CLI.

Comment: Still "not recommended for use in web environments" - as in, this will Crash And Burn at the worst possible moment.

Comment: @Piskvor: It won't 'crash and burn'. If run from a cgi environment, it will gracefully throw an error since pcntl function does not exist in the CGI version of PHP

Comment: @xbonez: Hmm, that would explain it - I've seen this on a web server, but it must have been hacked into the source by the locals, then. Explains the picturesque crashes.

Answer (score 0):

A general design patters would be to apply a Command Design Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

You can implement this in your local web environment or you could install some kind of queue server like: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ etc. etc.

It depends on your systems, access to them and your knowledge to see which solution would fit best That's a more complex question too far offtopic here.

In general the suggested pattern will allow you to fix your question without having lots of issues since it is a well-known and widely used approach to handle lots of tasks which take too long for doing directly within the request.