# Force download of a .txt file with button

Tags: jquery, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download File Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery)
>   [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

```
$('#download').click(function() {
    var url = 'http://www.mysite.com/123.txt';
    location.href = url;
});
```

The button causes the browser to browse to the file instead of prompting a download. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Apache as a web server add `.htaccess` to the folder with the following content:

```
<Files *.txt>
  ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</Files>
```

Comment: +1 nice solution (if the OP uses apache)

Comment: This seems to only work if the text file is in the same folder as my web page. If i put the text file inside a subfolder such as /test, the original problem persists. I have put an .htaccess with your code in both the sub folder and parent folder and the problem is still there.