# Download file from jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I have a java script file in which a variable has some string like:

```
var xw = 'Some content';
```

I want to download this string as a file. How to do this in JQuery/javascript? I don't want to send any request on server using AJAX. Is there any way to download in purely JQuery/javascript ?

Comment: Check this post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery

Comment: It works only when i have a file already created. But i don't have such type of any file.

Comment: Why can't you use a server side language or ajax?

Comment: This is a sample demo service. We are not using java and any other server side programming. This is normal HTML project.

Comment: Is there anyway to change the download file name? Right now it just shows as `download`?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,U29tZSBjb250ZW50">Download "Some content" as a text file</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5tJ5p/

Comment: How it is working? Do we need to encrypt data? Please can you explain it?

Comment: Yes, you need to encode data. In base64 in this case. Basically "U29tZSBjb250ZW50" is a base64 representation of "Some content" string. You can read more about this approach at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme. Please, consider browser adoption.

Comment: Is there any way so i don't need to encode? Or if i need to encode then how to encode it in javascript in optimized way.

Comment: You can encode a string as base64 in JavaScript using btoa() function. For example: `alert(btoa("Some content"));​`

Comment: Nice. I've never seen this before.

Comment: Thanx it worked for me.. :-) But i am not able to chenge name of file. Can we do it?

Comment: You can specify a download attribute on <a> tag, see http://jsfiddle.net/5tJ5p/1/, but again you need to check details about adoption. You can also take a look at Blob and File API that provides another way to achieve the same objective. See http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html as an example.

Comment: If i want to download using `window.location.href=URL` then how to use download attribute to change name of file?

Comment: From what I know currently it is not possible client side.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify).

Comment: Not sure if that's what he wants. But then again, the question is horribly vague...

Comment: Not really a pure javascript/jquery solution, but I use a similar hack to onclick copy to the clip board.

Comment: I think it's the best he's going to find.

Comment: As much as I hate to upvote something that requires Flash, there doesn't seem to be a better cross browser solution.