# Downloading a PDF (not opening it) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, download

I need to trigger a file download using Javascript when user clicks on a certain button. To do that I use:

```
window.open('my_url.com/my_file.pdf');
```

However, in Firefox this opens the PDF in a new tab. I'd like instead that the PDF file doesn't get opened but downloaded, with a dialog box asking for a folder in which downloading the file.

How to do that?

Comment: DUPE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery

Comment: Use http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

Comment: I do not think this can be done from Javascript (but I may be wrong); you need to serve the file with `Content-disposition: attachment` instead.

Comment: box86rowh: the solution given to the answer you mention just does the same thing as what I already have, it opens the PDF instead of downloading it.

Answer (score 2):

Download jquery plugin from [jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com)

In JS

```
    $.fileDownload('pdfDownload.php', {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        data: {},
        successCallback:function(){
        },
        failCallback:function(){
        }
    });
```

In PHP

**EDIT**

In `pdfDownload.php` do whatever you want

> // your PHP CODE 
>   // ....
>
> ```
>   header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
>   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=someName.pdf;');
>   readfile('path/to/someName.pdf');
> ```

Comment: This is for a normal href link to PDF. In my case it's a button that leads to whatever and to which I have attached a PDF file using Javascript (but the original function/destination of the button remains intact)

Comment: You mean you want to ask user from where to download it?

Comment: Well there's only 2 possibilities in Firefox: either a file is opened, or it is downloaded in which case the browser asks where to download it isn't it?

Comment: First of all this script works in any browser. Opened where? In browser? May be I got what you meant, look at update

Comment: If you want to send some data and recieve it on Server side use `data: {},` line from example. On server side you can get data from $_POST