# I want to know that when download of a file is completed at client side when he/she try to download a file from my application

Tags: browser, download

In my application , I have to provide a download button, so that when user clicks on it he/she can download file.

Right now in my application i have a feature that when user clicks on download button , I disable my download button until download pop-up is opened.

Now, I want that when download completes on client side , then download button should be enable to the client.

I want to know that is it possible ? If yes , then please tell me how can i achieve that.

Comment: are you using jQuery ? Follow link here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery

Comment: Hey , My problem is that when user click on "save" button in download window , then download will be start . I want that when this download is completed then my download button should be enable.

Comment: There are lots of solution to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax which refers to this link http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Answer (score 0):

From the `[link][1]` i Pasted , you can do this using jQuery :

Suppose you have an

```
<input id="FileDownload" type="button" name="FileDownload">Download</input>
```

You can define a `jQuery` event on the Click of this button

```
$("#FileDownlaod").click(function(){
this.disabled=true; //Disables the input button
/Call the plugin as described in the link
//On Success this.disabled=false
});
```