# How to download file in jQuery (already use href with preventDefault)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I a trying to download file when user click on "download like".I found this link .it open file.Not start download file automatically.
[Download File Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery).\

http://jsfiddle.net/fXwqA/

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css';
});
```

It should start download automatically .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need in jQuery, just add "download" attribute to your anchor:

```
<a download href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
   Download now!
</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/fXwqA/1/