# Download a file on page load in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I have a file in my server folder and now I want to download that file on page load.

**Example :**

If I click on Our products than a file has been downloaded automatically in users system from my server.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is my ans :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if('<?php echo $filename ?>' !=''){
        window.location.href ='/files/<?php echo $filename  ?>.xls';
        }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// in controller 

public function download() {
  $this->viewClass = 'Media';
  // Render app/webroot/files/example.docx
  $params = array(
    'id'        => 'example.docx', // file name
    'name'      => 'example',
    'extension' => 'docx', // its file extension name
    'mimeType'  => array(
        'docx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument' .
            '.wordprocessingml.document'
    ),
    'path'      => 'files' . DS
);
$this->set($params);
}


//In view file

echo $this->Html->url(array(
    "controller" => "controller_name",
     "action" => "action_name",
     "ext" => "file_extension_name"
));
```

Also read [Cakephp Media View](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html)