# Download a file using jquery redirect to the page instead of downloading

Tags: jquery

As i saw in some threads, i may download a file that way:

```
$('.download').click(function(){
     window.location.href = 'images/apple_juice.jpeg';
});
```

But instead i am getting a page presenting this image.

Comment: Generally speaking the browser will decide by the server headers whether to download the file. Do you have control over the server ?

Comment: Yes i do. With node.js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download File Using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery)

Comment: I suggest you edit the question according to your answer so it would be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, i have managed download using node.js:

```
backup.get('/download-backup-file&:file_name', function(req, res){

    var file_name = req.params.file_name.split('=')[1];
    var file = 'backups/'+file_name;
    res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.

});
```