# Trigger a browser download with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, download

My goal is to let a user download a PDF from my server. 
The most common approach to this would be to simply have a link with a download attribute like so

```
<a href="http://mysource.pdf" download>click here</a>
```

The problem with this is that I cannot monitor the download or have a callback when it is finished. The browser just hangs until the request is processed and suddenly pops up a download when it is done. 
So now I am getting pdf data from a server with AJAX and want to download the data via the browser.
So I have something along the lines of

```
$.get("http://mysource.pdf", (data) ->
  #need to somehow trigger a download with this data
)
```

I've been searching for a while to no avail. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

--edit To clarify why this is not a duplicate, I am asking about triggering a download on data, not a local file.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery)

Comment: search "monitor download progress with javascript" Most solutions seem to require server-side intervention.

Comment: I would like to point out that this is NOT a duplicate of the linked thread. That thread is asking about downloading a file. I am downloading data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    $.get("http://mysource.pdf", (data) ->
      window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    )

});
```