# Downloading different type of files through only one Rest web services call

Tags: java, rest, web-services, file, postman

I have requirement like i want to download a file through rest web services but it can be jpg, jpeg, pdf, png anything I have written code like below but irts not working properly.

```
 @GET
     @Path("/UploadProfileImage")
    // @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
     public Response getFileuploaded(@HeaderParam("filetoopen")String filetoopen) {


         ResponseBuilder response=null;

            File file = new File(filetoopen);  
            System.out.println(filetoopen);
           response = Response.ok((Object) file);  
            response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filetoopen + "\"");  


         return response.build(); 


     }
```

here in filetoopen parameter i am passing fully qualified name of file. means with location. i am trying to download file with POSTMAN API but it not coming properly. screenshot attached.

[image: POSTMAN API checks TO DOWNLOAD AS AN ATTACHMENT]

Comment: Take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542639/jax-rs-file-downloads-multiple-content-types

Comment: yes similiar I tried , but i am not getting dialogue box to download file .

Comment: actually i need a webservices which can open all files type as above i mentioned in dialogue box to save