# onClick event and data-toggle

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using this piece of code in a function but its really buggy, the modal opens but the download doesn't.

I need the modal to open and the download happen in the background.

```
echo "<a id='download-item' class='button left' onclick='count();' href='".$mp3->guid."' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Download</a>";
```

Comment: What does `$mp3->guid` return? And what is the filename? What do you mean by buggy? Any error's thrown?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set the " and ' correctly:

```
echo "<a id='download-item' class='button left' onclick='count();' href='".$mp3->guid."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Download</a>";
```

And then make the function count() call the desired file to download:

[Download File Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You should put the download attribute at the  tag

```
echo "<a id='download-item' download='filename.mp3' class='button left' onclick='count();' href='".$mp3->guid."' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Download</a>";
```

this might works fine

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a closer look at the bootstrap implementation, but I think the `data-toggle` handler uses `event.preventDefault()` which prevents the file from being downloaded (assuming that you start the download in your `click()` function.

I tested the following code locally and the modal opened the same time as the download started:

```
echo "<a id='download-item' class='button left' onclick='jQuery(\"#myModal\").modal();' href='".$mp3->guid."' download>Download</a>";
```