# How to download a text file onclick using javascript or HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to download a .txt on click it. i am using the below html code:

```
<a href="d:/file.txt">Download</a>
```

this code is working for .docx files not for .txt file.

Comment: You can't download files from your own computer trough the browser.

Comment: But it is working for all other types of files right. its only not working for .txt files.

Comment: What is not working? You mean it's opening the file instead of dowloading? If so, add download to your link. Like `<a download href="xx">Download</a>`

Comment: Yah i also tried this way but it is still opening in browser instead of download.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `file:` protocol. Otherwise, the browser thinks that `d:` is a protocol name. You also need the `download` attribute to make it download the file instead of displaying it in the browser.

So it should be:

```
<a href="file:///d:/file.txt" download>Download</a>
```

But this seems pointless. The file `d:/file.txt` is already on your computer, why do you need to download it? Normally you download a file from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Text files are displayed in the browser when the content-type is sent as text. You should Try to send it with a different content-type or use a language such as PHP to send it as a download.

Comment: Yah i think thats a good one. is there any way to download .docx file as .txt file

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
<a href="d:/file.txt" download="my_text_file">Download</a>
```

The `download="my_text_file"` attribute indicates that the target will be downloaded when clicked on the link.. and my_text_file will be new name for that file...

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer from @barmar:

Taking the jquery question tag into consideration, check out [Download File Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296085/6010052).
Here's the code example from that post:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'uploads/file.doc';
});

<a href="no-script.html">Download now!</a>
```

You can change the value assigned to window.location.href to the file you would like to download.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<a href="d:/file.txt" download>Download</a>
```

It is working for me.

Cheers

Comment: Ohh, then why it is not working in my case. i am using google chrome. and same code copy pasted from here.

Comment: What happens when you press the link? It just straight up opens the file instead of opening the download promt? 
I tried it on Firefox, altho this solution is supposed to be working in all browsers. Have you tested on Firefox?