# Download file not appear using jQuery

Tags: jquery

There are two objectives that I want, 1st is to hide the URL when mouse hover (Success). 2nd is to download the file when `<a>` is clicked.

Current problem is when I click at the `<a>` tag, an error appear.

[My Reference](https://allinworld99.blogspot.com/2015/02/hide-url-hover-over-link-hide-link-from.html)

What I have tried as below:

1. console when click at Download

[image]

2. At Inspect > Element:

[image]

Code:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    ...
    columns: [
        { data : "filename",
            render: function (data){
                var test = 'uploads/upload_file/'+filename;
                console.log(test); // I got uploads/upload_file/TEST 1.pdf
                return "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='location.href="+test+"'>Download</a>"
            }
        },
    ],
});
```

Comment: Your error is because of last `+` in your render function `return "<a [...]</a>" +` statement. To hide url, put redirect same way as you do with `TEST 1.pdf`

Comment: I've update the posting, already remove `+` and still no download triggered. For the hide url is success.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved by try this solution.

[THE ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887794/1556601)

1. Create a php file called `file_download.php`

> header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_REQUEST['f']);
> readfile('uploads/upload_file/'.$_REQUEST['f']);  exit;

2. Put this in jQuery function

> function downloadFile(filename){
> window.location.href = 'file_download.php?f='+ filename; }